# Exclude a list of directories from unix find command

Tags: bash, find

I need to build a list of files present in a directory but also pass in a file containing a list of directories to exclude.

I've seen the below suggestion but I've had no luck with it when it comes to the type flag:

```
find $dir_name $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat $exclude_file))
```

Is there a way I can do it or will I need to create the entire list and then work through it removing ones that partially match ones in the exclude directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've had no luck with it when it comes to the type flag"? Can you show the exact command you're running that doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that your `exclude_file` contains paths, not names, you need to use `-path` to match its entries. To exclude matching directories’ subdirectories, you also need to `-prune` them. This should work:

```
find . -type d \( $(printf -- "-path */%s -o " $(cat "$exclude_file")) -false \) -prune -o -print
```

If you only want to see files, you can print only files:

```
find . -type d \( $(printf -- "-path */%s -o " $(cat "$exclude_file")) -false \) -prune -o -type f -print
```

Comment: I've edited this answer, you needed `--` in-between `printf "-path"`, or you'll get an "Invalid option -p" due to printf trying to parse it.

Comment: Thanks @Someguy123; I tested with `zsh`, which doesn’t need `--`, but `bash` does indeed.